# how to add dependencies to the paperclip gem file

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The error occured while trying 'rails g paperclip photo data' is: 
Make sure all dependencies are added to Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)

using rails 3.0.3

my gem file:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc2'
# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'
gem 'sqlite3'
# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'paperclip', '2.3.3'


# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# To use Jbuilder templates for JSON
# gem 'jbuilder'

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'
```

Comment: You should tell a little more. How does your Gemfile look like? What version of Rails do you use? etc. Please, reedit your question.

Comment: Have you run `bundle install` or `bundle update` after you have added 'paperclip' to your Gemfile? I am sorry that I don't have time to thoroughly address your problem, but I hope someone wiser will. :(

Comment: You say that you're using **rails 3.0.0**. But in your **Gemfile** you've written `gem 'rails', '3.2.0.rc2'` have you tried `bundle install` as @Arsen7 has mentioned??

Answer (score -1):

Update with your Gemfile with gem 'rmagick', '2.13.1'

Or

sudo apt-get install imagemagick

Then run the command "which convert" it will display the path of imagemagic.